# Why does Git prints an incorrect diff at the bottom of a commit message?

Tags: windows, git, diff, pre-commit

I use a `pre-commit` hook to run `Prettier` formatter against my `HTML` documents:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Retrieving a list of the staged files
stagedFiles=$(git diff --staged --name-only)

# Format staged files automatically
echo "Formatting with Prettier..."
npx prettier --write $stagedFiles
git add $stagedFiles
```

The formatting successfully applies right after I enter `git commit` command and right before my configured editor opens the commit message. According to `commit.verbose` setting, `Git` appends there a diff showing what is to be committed, but this diff does not take into account changes made by `Prettier` — it demonstrates the unformatted version of my code. If I then abort the commit (leaving the message empty), I can see that no unstaged changes are in the repository; it means that all formatting modifications had been properly staged during execution of the `pre-commit` hook. Moreover, if I write some text to the message and complete the commit without aborting, the resulting snapshot **does** contain all formatting that was missing in the diff.

I finally concluded that the diff lies. But does a solution exist?

`Git for Windows` version: `2.33.0`

OS: `Windows 10 21h1 x64`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is : the `pre-commit` hook is not intended to modify files to be committed.

You can relate to the following rationale : the content you commit will be the exact content you could review and test *before* running `git commit`.

(the technical reason is : `git` creates the tree -- the content for the commit -- that will be used *before* calling the `pre-commit` hook)

A `pre-commit` hook should be written as a read-only action, which may prevent the commit from happening, e.g : if a file is not formatted correctly, reject the commit with a message "please run `format.sh` before committing".

Of course, you could work your way around that, but, FWIW, I advise you to follow this rule.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, but is there an ideologically correct method to perform tasks like autoformatting?

Comment: I'd say one option is to trigger it on `ctrl + S` in your IDE ? a simple enough way could be to add a git alias which runs "format + add + commit".

Comment: Do note that running `git add $filename` adds *the complete file*, which does not work well with `git add -p` for example, or with "I have a staged version, and extra modifications on disk".

Comment: Note that "format during saving" is one method, but another is to run a script: "format, add, and commit". The format-during-saving method has the advantage that your editor / IDE will probably show you the updated formatting, though.